# trouble using knockout js to display data on page - data not showing

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, json, knockout.js, knockout-mvc

This is my first time working and trying out knockout js and i am having trouble getting it to work. What i am doing is displaying a list/collection being returned from the database - basically a get of all users with their information.

**Problem:**  with what i have written so far i am not getting the data to display on the page and not sure what i am doing wrong or missing. If i am missing any other code that will help resolve my issue let me know. Thanks!

**View Page**

```
@using ProjectB.Shared.Models
@using System.Collections
@using ProjectB.Shared.Services
<html>
<head>
<script type ="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/knockout-2.2.1.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/knockout.mapping-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table data-bind="visible: RosterUsers().length>0">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Content Role</td>
        <td>Email</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody data-bind="foreach: RosterUsers">
    <tr>
        <td><span data-bind="text: Name"></span></td>
        <td><span data-bind="text: ContentRole"></span></td>
        <td><span data-bind="text: Email"></span></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<script type ="text/javascript">
    var rUserViewModel = function () {
            var self = this;
            self.Name = ko.observable("");
            self.ContentRole = ko.observable("");
            self.Email = ko.observable("");

            var rUserData = {
                Name: self.Name,
                ContentRole: self.ContentRole,
                Email: self.Email
            };

            self.RosterUsers = ko.observableArray([]);

            GetRosterUser();

            function GetRosterUser() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "/api/RosterApiController",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        self.RosterUsers(data);
                    },
                    error: function (error) {
                        alert(error.status + " <--and--> " + error.statusText);
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        ko.applyBindings(new rUserViewModel());
</script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**Model**

```
 public partial class RosterVw
    {
        public RosterVw()
        {
            this.Users = new HashSet<RosterUser>();
        }
        public ICollection<RosterUser> Users { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class RosterUser
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ContentRoles ContentRole { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; } //Photo is unique to email address
    }
```

Comment: There does not seem to be anything wrong with the Knockout code you've written.  Here is a fiddle that shows it working - http://jsfiddle.net/jearles/nKJm7/.  If you set a breakpoint in the success handler of your AJAX call do you hit it? If so verify that the returned JSON meets your ViewModel expectations.  Also check the browser debug console for any logged error messages.

Comment: I tried debugging but i never hit anything in the javascript. I will try to play around keeping your suggestions in thought. thanks

Comment: Where on your page do you have the script tag that initializes the ViewModel?  Are you loading knockout.js in the HEAD? If you cannot break in the success handler it would seem that the something is off. What if you set a breakpoint at the .ajax call... does that get executed? Try the same with the ko.applyBindings call.

Comment: @JohnEarles i added everything that i have showing on my view.cshtml page check code above. I tried the ajax call and tried the first line of the javascript but still not hitting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code I suppose that you are using ASP.NET WebAPI. I thing that you should change your ajax call address from `/api/RosterApiController` to `/api/RosterApi`.

Both ASP.NET MVC and ASP.NET WebAPI have routing convention that except controller name **without** `Controller` suffix.

Answer (score 0):

I think Slawomir solution is definitely something you should be aware of but you can try to populate your RosterUsers using a foreach.

```
_.each(data, function(user){
    self.RosterUsers.push(new RosterUserObject(user));
});
```